# How to force lazy value computation

Tags: scala, lazy-evaluation

What is the idiomatic scala way to force computation on lazy value?

Comment: Call it, or don't make it lazy.

Comment: Why do you want to force a lazy value computation ? Why do you make it lazy ? It really looks like a code smell...

Comment: I make it lazy to untie knot with mutual dependencies over immutable data structures. I need to force it in right place to untie dependencies in a way to escape stack overflow with uncontrolled recursion.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just call it:

```
lazy val x = someOperation()
// ...
x
```